# how to limit the amount of digits of a function in Julia

Tags: performance, julia

my function has to work with very big numbers, so in order to do that I used parts in my code such as `big()` . Unfortunately this resulted in giving me a result that is too precise (in other words its slowing the entire code down).

This is how the result looks like.

```
ΔE = 0.08298347005140644564908076516066986088852555871299296314640532293721884964540988
```

If possible I would like to limit the result to 4 digits

```
ΔE = 0.0829
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is a concern, probably the best way to do this is with https://github.com/dzhang314/MultiFloats.jl, e.g.

```
using MultiFloats
x = Float64x4(2.0)
# Calculations performed on x will have Float64x4 precision subsequently...
```

MultiFloats.jl appears to be the fastest package around at present for such calculations, and will let you choose from precision levels between `Float64x2` and `Float64x8`. In any event, this will be dramatically faster than the `BigFloat`s used in the example above.